Have multiple islands across Nintendo profiles - Animal Crossing: New Horizons
In Animal Crossing: New Horizons, on the Nintendo Switch, you share exact same island and save file across Nintendo profiles (different characters though).
Is there a way to “split” the save file so everyone has their own save files across Nintendo accounts (loss of save data is acceptable)?

The save system for Animal Crossing is special to this game: there can be only one island per game console, it is not linked to a Nintendo account or user profile.
The official FAQ does have a question confirming this:

You can only create one island per Nintendo Switch system, even if you use multiple games. A different system is required to create a different island.
The island save data is saved on the Nintendo Switch system, so there will only be one island (save file), even if different games are used on the same system.

So no, there is no official method to have separate save file, beside buying a new console.
